# What does objMessage.bcc do?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to to know what is the difference between:

```
objMessage.Bcc
```

and

```
objMessage.To
```

on `asp.net`.

Comment: `To` and `Bcc` fields are not specific to `ASP.NET`. You can find out immediately, if you google it.

Comment: What is objMessages type?